# Find a sequence of functions

Tags: derivatives, sequence-of-function

There are familiar functions whose derivatives are periodic. $e^x$ has a period of $1$, since

$$\frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x$$

And $\sin(x)$ has a period of $4$. I am interested in finding a sequence of functions $f_n$ such that for any $n$, we have

$$ \frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}f_n = f_n $$

But for any $0<m<n$

$$ \frac{d^{m}}{dx^{m}} f_n \neq f_n $$

This is just a fancy way of asking if we can find functions that have a period of $n$ with respect to the derivative, for any $n$. We can easily construct such a sequence using a taylor series, by setting

$$f_n= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{kn}}{(kn)!} $$

(Note that $f_1(x) = e^x$)

But I am interested in a solution that doesn't rely on the use of infinite series. Does anyone have am interesting solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something to notice before we move into the general solution: you mention that $e^x$ has period 1 and $\sin x$ (and $\cos x$) have period 4. Note that
\begin{align*}
\cos x + i \sin x &= e^{ix} & \cos x - i \sin x &= e^{-ix}
\end{align*}
Note also that $e^{-x}$ has period 2. We see how for periods 1, 2, and 4, the functions we seek are all of the form $e^{\alpha x}$.

How can we take this observation to find the functions with period $n$? Suppose our function is $f(x) = e^{\alpha x}$. Then we have
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(x) = \frac{d^n}{dx^n} e^{\alpha x} = \alpha^n e^{\alpha x} = \alpha^n f(x)$$
When is it the case that $\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(x) = f(x)$? Precisely when $\alpha^n = 1$. There are $n$ complex numbers $\alpha$ that satisfy $\alpha^n = 1$; those are numbers of the form
$$\alpha = \cos \left(\frac{2k\pi}n \right) + i \sin\left( \frac{2k\pi}n \right)$$
where $k=0, \ldots, n-1$. We have
\begin{align*}
&e^{\left( \cos \left(\frac{2k\pi}n \right) + i \sin\left( \frac{2k\pi}n \right) \right) x} \\
&= e^{\cos \left(\frac{2k\pi}n \right)x} \cdot e^{i \sin\left( \frac{2k\pi}n \right)x} \\
&= e^{\cos \left(\frac{2k\pi}n \right)x} \left( \cos \left( \sin\left( \frac{2k\pi}n \right)x \right) + i \sin \left( \sin\left( \frac{2k\pi}n \right)x \right)\right)
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
&e^{\left( \cos \left(\frac{2(n-k)\pi}n \right) + i \sin\left( \frac{2(n-k)\pi}n \right) \right) x} \\&= e^{\cos \left(\frac{2k\pi}n \right)x} \cdot e^{i \sin\left( \frac{2k\pi}n \right)x} \\&= e^{\cos \left(\frac{2k\pi}n \right)x} \left( \cos \left( \sin\left( \frac{2k\pi}n \right)x \right) - i \sin \left( \sin\left( \frac{2k\pi}n \right)x \right)\right)
\end{align*}
so in fact the functions (obtained by adding and subtracting the previous two functions)
\begin{align*}
f_k^+(x) &= e^{\cos \left(\frac{2k\pi}n \right)x} \cos \left( \sin\left( \frac{2k\pi}n \right)x \right) & f_k^-(x) &= e^{\cos \left(\frac{2k\pi}n \right)x} \sin \left( \sin\left( \frac{2k\pi}n \right)x \right)
\end{align*}
each have period $n$. Here $k$ ranges from $0$ to $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ (we don't go all the way to $n$ because $f_{n-k}^+ = f_k^+$ and $f_{n-k}^- = -f_k^-$, so to go beyond $n/2$ would be to repeat functions). Note that $f_0^- = 0$, and if $n$ is even, then $f_{n/2}^- = 0$. As such, the functions $f_k^{\pm}$ comprise $n$ distinct functions. Note that if $f$ and $g$ each have period $n$, then so do $Af + Bg$ where $A$ and $B$ are constants. As such, any linear combination of the aforementioned functions has period $n$ (more precisely, it has period dividing $n$, but it satisfies that it is equal to its own $n$th derivative in any case).

Note that the functions you're looking for are in fact the solutions to the differential equation
$$f^{(n)} - f = 0$$
This is an $n$th order linear homogeneous ordinary differential equation, so its solution space has dimension $n$. Indeed, then, we have covered all solutions.

Comment: Thank you, your solution is very concise. I am however curious as to which choice of $k$ /which linear combination produces the series expansion solution in my question, since it appears that all the solutions you provided have some periodicity, whereas the series expansion solution has none

Comment: These solutions don't generally have periodicity, as they all have that exponential component which is not periodic. To find which linear combination equals your series expansion, we could compute the first $n$ coefficients of the Taylor series for each function and note that (I suspect) the coefficient vectors are linearly independent. Then finding the proper linear combination reduces to solving a system of equations.